# In Swift, how can you ensure that only one of two text fields is fillable?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, textfield

Say you have an email field and a cell phone field. If the user fills in the email field, the cell phone field cannot be filled anymore, visa versa.

Here is what I tried below. Making the one field the delegate of the other currently only prevents "Done" from exiting the keyboard, it doesn't make the other text field inactive.

In viewDidLoad

```
 self.cellField.delegate = emailField as? UITextFieldDelegate
```

then outside

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(cellField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if emailField.text?.isEmpty == false {
    return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
 } //// I also tried textFieldDidBeginEditing
```

Comment: As a recommendation, this is going to be a really confusing user interface for your users.  If they see two fields presented together they will be inclined to fill out both.  If one disables when they start entering a value I think that would be very unexpected.  Perhaps there is some way to make it clearer that the user has an either-or choice then present the one field related to that choice.  Or let the user fill in both then let them choose which they want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make both

```
self.cellField.delegate = self
self.emailField.delegate = self
```

---

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if textField == cellField {
     return emailField.text!.isEmpty
  } else if textField == emailField {
     return cellField.text!.isEmpty
  } 
  return true 
}
```

Comment: thanks. It works. Now I add add an IBAction at each to make an alert if the other is filled.

Comment: just a side effect question: if cell field is entered it correctly inactivates email field, however it also inactivates a 3rd field (password). that does not happen when email is entered; in that case cell field is inactivates and password not - this is correct. Do you know why this might be?